# Relation Between Special and Generic Fibers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If X is a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-scheme whose special fiber is smooth projective Calabi-Yau (trivial canonical bundle), does that imply that its generic fiber is also smooth projective Calabi-Yau? If not, how much of the data can be salvaged? Under what additional conditions can all conditions be transferred to the generic fiber? Even more generally, what properties of the special fiber in "nice" situations can be transferred to properties of the generic fiber?

Comment: You should at least assume $X \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z_p$ is flat and projective, and maybe $X$ integral or something. Assuming proper in stead of projective is usually not enough: sometimes the special fibre is projective but the generic fibre does not admit an ample line bundle (I'm not sure if there are examples with CY special fibre, but I see no reason why there can't be).

Comment: Assuming that $X$ is $\mathbb{Z}_p$-flat and projective, if the (geometric) special fiber has numerically trivial canonical divisor class, then also the geometric generic fiber has numerically trivial canonical divisor class.  In characteristic $0$, there is a classification of such Kaehler manifolds due to de Rham, Berger, Beauville, Bogomolov, et al.  In particular, there is a finite etale cover of the geometric generic fiber that has trivial canonical bundle.

Comment: It is worth pointing that the finite etale cover Jason Starr mentions is necessary. For example, there is an Enriques surface over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ whose reduction modulo $2$ has trivial canonical class.